# Xcode 4 - Tab Bar application - Problem in executing third tab

Tags: ipad, xcode4, uitabbar, ios4

I have Xcode 4 and I created an application using the Tab Bar template (and not View based app). There is a **UISwitch** in each of these tabs and when I change it, a **UILabel** switches between *ON* and *OFF*. Very simple app and no confusion. Xcode 4 creates two tabs for me by default. I need a third tab as well, so I drag **TabBarItem** from the Objects Library and drop it on the existing **TabBarController.** I create a new file, subclass of **UIViewController** and the following code goes into three tabs.

The following is the interface

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    UISwitch *switch1;
    UILabel *status1;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *switch1;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *status1;
- (IBAction) switch1Change;
@end
```

The following is the implementation

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize switch1;
@synthesize status1;
- (IBAction) switch1Change
{
    if (switch1.on) 
        status1.text = @"ON";
    else
        status1.text = @"OFF";
}
```

The same code repeats for SecondViewController and ThirdViewController with ivars changing to switch2,status2 and switch3,status3. The link to the project is [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?lwowxeaba23bpjj)

When I run it on the simulator, everything works fine for the first and second tab. When I open the third tab, I get the following error **"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: [ setValue: forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-complaint for the key switch3."**

When I remove the UISwitch from the **ThirdView.xib**, I don't get this error. Only when I add the switch control, I get this error. Can somebody please explain what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Interface Builder, your third view controller is of class `UIViewController` (and doesn't have outlets for status3 or switch3). Change its class to `ThirdViewController`, wire up the outlets, and it should work.

Comment: All I can say is "damn" to myself and "Wow, thank you" to you sir. You're the best!